# convert image to rgb code

Tags: java, image, rgb, pixel

I am a no IT person. But I am working on converting the image pixel to R,G,B code. I would like to ask you if there is any software can help. I don't know nothing about coding, so when I read some articles here, I got lost . Do you have any tool that help me? Please give me some instruction. Thanks

Comment: In case you are looking for software, please check the http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ site. Otherwise please add further details what technology you want to use.

Comment: What has java to do with this question?

Answer (score 2):

As a "non-IT person", you can use the pippet option of MS paint, or any other decent image editor in order to get an RGB code from a given pixel.

Now if you want to automatize this, you'll need to code a bit and maybe have a look at this question [Need Faster way to get RGB value for each Pixel of a Buffered Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088465/need-faster-way-to-get-rgb-value-for-each-pixel-of-a-buffered-image)

Comment: thank you @Gammaitoni. I think I need to read from the abc of this. But, I 'd like to ask. how can I run the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "Paint" software in windows for this

[image]